# Eclipse + Jython: Python module not found using one-to-one object factory

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython, pydev

I'm trying to get an Eclipse Java project using a Python module (in Eclipse) running, but I keep getting an error saying my Python module can't be found. I'm following the approach explained in *The Definitive Guide to Python*, "More Detailed One-to-One Object Factories". I think there's a problem with my project configuration/path settings, but I can't figure out what exactly.

This is the error message:

```
PYTHONPATH: ['.', '/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython_2.2.3.2011100616/Lib']
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
ImportError: No module named building
```

The Python path was retrieved from `state.path` (where `state` is an instance of `PySystemState`).

So far I've defined the relevant Java interface, implemented the Python module, and put it all on the classpath. Also, the project has both the Java and PyDev nature added, and also the Python source folder is on the PYTHONPATH. I still get the above mentioned error. Do I need to add the Python source folder (containing the module) somewhere else?

**Update:** as suggested by Fabio (see below), I've added the Java bin files to the Python path and removed the Java source files. That didn't solve anything, so here are my project configuration files.

My PyDev configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?eclipse-pydev version="1.0"?>

<pydev_project>
<pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_INTERPRETER">jython</pydev_property>
<pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_VERSION">jython 2.7</pydev_property>
<pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_SOURCE_PATH">
<path>/SampleJythonIntegration/pysrc</path>
<path>/SampleJythonIntegration/bin</path>
</pydev_pathproperty>
</pydev_project>
```

My Java configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>SampleJythonIntegration</name>
<comment></comment>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.python.pydev.PyDevBuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.python.pydev.pythonNature</nature>
</natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 0):

For PyDev, in a Java project, you have to add the bin folder to the PYTHONPATH (i.e.: the folder with the .class files and not the one with the .java files).

See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html (the last part) for a proper reference.

Comment: did so, however my java interface still can't be found by the python class implementing the like. any other suggestions, maybe based on the modified questions? thanks a lot!